# PayPal REST API 500 internal service error only in live

Tags: rest, paypal

I am using the Paypal PHP REST API SDK, but I can reproduce the problem using curl too. I am able to get a token without a problem. This only occurs when I'm submitting a live payment. I can switch to sandbox and submit an identical payment successfully.

As you can see below this is a very basic payment. I don't see how there could possibly be a problem with the information being submitted.
I have no shortage of debug IDs since this happens every time, but here is the last one I got: 049eee254433f

```
{
  "intent":"sale",
  "payer":{
    "payment_method":"credit_card",
    "funding_instruments":[
      {
        "credit_card":{
          "type":"visa",
          "number":"(removed)",
          "cvv2":"(removed)",
          "expire_month":"1",
          "expire_year":"2016",
          "first_name":"(removed)",
          "last_name":"(removed)"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "transactions":[
    {
      "amount":{
        "total":"11.98",
        "currency":"USD"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, according to the debug ID, is that you are not sending the billing address along with the card information. The option to include/not include the billing address with your request is based upon your merchant account setup. In order to rectify the above error, please provide the billing address in your request.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#creditcard-object

Comment: I'm having a similar issue - where can I lookup the debug message from the returned debug ID?

Comment: The only message you will see is the internal server error that's returned with the http 500. I've put in a request for better error messaging for this particular instance as well as better error messaging in general instead of a generic Internal Server Error.

Comment: @PP_MTS_Cory Where can I go to change the "merchant account setup" to not require the billing address for CC payments?

Comment: @Chris - you would need to contact PayPal customer support for assistance with that. You can click 'contact us' at the bottom of any PayPal page for contact information.